# Implementing the birthday paradox continuation of elliptic curve factorization

Tags: python, primes, factorization

I would like to add the birthday paradox continuation of the elliptic curve factorization algorithm to my [collection](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/themes/#Prime%20Numbers) of factoring programs. Brent describes the algorithm in [two](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3366.pdf) [papers](http://pdf.aminer.org/001/011/657/factorization_of_the_tenth_fermat_number.pdf), Montgomery also [describes](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7/) the algorithm, and I am trying to implement the algorithm according to a detailed [description](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/164495/files/nscan12.pdf) by Bosma and Lenstra. Here is what I have so far, in Python, which you can run at [ideone.com/vMXSab](http://ideone.com/vMXSab):

```
# lenstra's algorithm per bosma/lenstra

from random import randint
from fractions import gcd

def primes(n):
    b, p, ps = [True] * (n+1), 2, []
    for p in xrange(2, n+1):
        if b[p]:
            ps.append(p)
            for i in xrange(p, n+1, p):
                b[i] = False
    return ps

def bezout(a, b):
    if b == 0: return 1, 0, a
    q, r = divmod(a, b)
    x, y, g = bezout(b, r)
    return y, x-q*y, g

def add(p, q, a, b, m):
    if p[2] == 0: return q
    if q[2] == 0: return p
    if p[0] == q[0]:
        if (p[1] + q[1]) % m == 0:
            return 0, 1, 0 # infinity
        n = (3 * p[0] * p[0] + a) % m
        d = (2 * p[1]) % m
    else:
        n = (q[1] - p[1]) % m
        d = (q[0] - p[0]) % m
    x, y, g = bezout(d, m)
    if g > 1: return 0, 0, d # failure
    z = (n*x*n*x - p[0] - q[0]) % m
    return z, (n * x * (p[0] - z) - p[1]) % m, 1

def mul(k, p, a, b, m):
    r = (0,1,0)
    while k > 0:
        if k % 2 == 1:
            r = add(p, r, a, b, m)
            if r[2] > 1: return r
        k = k // 2
        p = add(p, p, a, b, m)
        if p[2] > 1: return p
    return r

def lenstra1(n, limit):
    g = n
    while g == n:
        q = randint(0, n-1), randint(0, n-1), 1
        a = randint(0, n-1)
        b = (q[1]*q[1] - q[0]*q[0]*q[0] - a*q[0]) % n
        g = gcd(4*a*a*a + 27*b*b, n)
    if g > 1: return 0, g # lucky factor
    for p in primes(limit):
        pp = p
        while pp < limit:
            q = mul(p, q, a, b, n)
            if q[2] > 1:
                return 1, gcd(q[2], n)
            pp = p * pp
    return False

def parms(b1):
    b2 = 10 * b1
    er = [(1,31), (2,63), (3,127), (6,255), (12,511), \
          (18,511), (24,1023), (30,1023), (60,2047)]
    prev = 1,31
    for (e, r) in er:
        if e*e > b1/1250: break
        prev = e, r
    e, r = prev
    rBar = int(round(b2/r))
    u = randint(0, pow(2,30)//(e+2))
    v = randint(0, pow(2,30)//(e+2))
    uBar = randint(0, pow(2,30)//(e+2))
    vBar = randint(0, pow(2,30)//(e+2))
    return b2, e, r, rBar, u, v, uBar, vBar

def lenstra2(n, b1):
    g = n
    while g == n:
        q = randint(0, n-1), randint(0, n-1), 1
        a = randint(0, n-1)
        b = (q[1]*q[1] - q[0]*q[0]*q[0] - a*q[0]) % n
        g = gcd(4*a*a*a + 27*b*b, n)
    if g > 1: return 0, g # lucky factor
    for p in primes(b1):
        pp = p
        while pp < b1:
            q = mul(p, q, a, b, n)
            if q[2] > 1: return 1, gcd(q[2], n)
            pp = p * pp
    b2, e, r, rBar, u, v, uBar, vBar = parms(b1)
    f = [1] * (r+1)
    for i in range(1, r):
        p = mul(pow(u*i+v,e), q, a, b, n)
        if p[2] > 1: return 2, gcd(p[2], n)
        f[i] = (f[i-1] * (q[0] - p[0])) % n
    d = 1
    for j in range(1, rBar):
        pBar = mul(pow(uBar*j+vBar,e), q, a, b, n)
        if pBar[2] > 1: return 3, gcd(pBar[2], n)
        t = 0
        for i in range(0, r):
            t = (t + p[0] * f[i]) % n
        d = (d * t) % n
    g = gcd(d, n)
    if 1 < g < n: return 4, g
    return False
```

The `primes` function implements a simple version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, returning a list of prime numbers less than *n*, and the `bezout` function implements the extended Euclidean algorithm, returning the inverse of *a*, the inverse of *b*, and their greatest common divisor. The elliptic arithmetic is given by the `add` and `mul` functions; add returns a "point" (0, 0, *d*) to signal a non-invertible denominator, `mul` propagates it, and uses of `mul` in the factoring functions must check it each time `mul` is called. Function `lenstra1` is a simple one-stage version of elliptic curve factorization, and works properly.

Function `lenstra2` and its auxiliary function `parms` are my attempt to implement the algorithm given in the Bosma/Lenstra [paper](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/164495/files/nscan12.pdf) cited above. I'm first trying to get a basic version working, as described in section 6.1, without considering the optimizations in sections 6.4 and 6.7. I think the calculations in `parms` are correct. The function runs, but always returns `False`, indicating that it did not find a factor, or it returns after an early break in the elliptic arithmetic before completing the algorithm and returning from the final `gcd` calculation. I think the problem is in the computation of the coefficients of *f*, and in the use of *f* to calculate *d*.

So my questions:

1. Have I correctly calculated the coefficients of *f*?
2. Have I correctly calculated the value of *d*?
3. How do I implement the optimizations of sections 6.4 and 6.7? I don't understand either of them.
4. How do I implement the Suyama curve of section 5.1 using Weierstrass coordinates?

Many thanks.

Comment: You have an awful lot of reputation for not having a username.

Comment: May I suggest some test-driven programming here?  Starting from the innermost functions, extract from the paper the exact intent of each function.  Come up with various examples of arguments and expected return value.  Write them down as runnable tests, and make sure that they pass.  Then repeat for the other functions until you have covered the whole program.

Comment: @ArminRigo: Test-driven programming is not the answer. I know how to program. But I don't understand the algorithm, and don't have any test cases to rely on, so I can't write any tests.

Comment: In order to debug it you need to understand it.  Writing tests is one way to learn it.